# HTML/CSS Elemento fora do lugar

Tags: html, css, posicionamento

Não sei onde estou errando, mas meu footer fica no meio da página.
É meu futuro portefólio, então nem tudo vai ser definitivo.
Outras sugestões são bem-vindas.

```css
*{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 font-family:'Open Sans';
}

header{
 width: 100%;
 height: 65px;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 1;
}

h1{
 padding: 20px;
}

#menu ul{
 margin-right: 5%;
}

#menu li{
 margin-right: 0.5%;
 display: inline;
 padding: 20px;
 float: right;
}

#menu li a{
 color: #ffffff;
 font-family: 'Open Sans';
 text-decoration: none;
 padding: 10px;
}
#menu a:hover{
 text-decoration: underline;
}

h1{
 margin-left: 5%;
 color:#fff;
 text-decoration: none;
 float: left;
 font-size: 20px;
}

#banner{
 position: relative;
 background:url(img/code-3.jpeg) no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100vh;
 background-position:0px 0px ;
 /*margin-bottom: 30px;*/
}

#banner p{
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;
 color: #fff;
 font-family: 'Open Sans';
 font-size: 3.5em;
 top:48%;
 /*left: 400px;*/
}

.secao{
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 /*height: 100vh;*/
 background-color: #eee;
}

.servicos{
 padding: 1.5%;
 margin-top: 60px;
 margin-left: 10%;
 width: 35%;
 float: left;
 border-radius:7px;
 /*height: 300px;*/
 color:#2d2d2d;
 /*background-color: #eee;*/
 text-align: center;
}

.servicos h2{
 font-family: 'Roboto';
 font-size: 2.4em;
 margin-bottom: 2%;
}

.servicos p{
 font-family: 'Open Sans';
 font-size: 120%;
 line-height: 30px;
 
}

.tecnologias{
 margin:10% 0;
 width: 100%; 
}

.tecnologias h2{
 margin-bottom: 4%;
}

.tecno{
 display: inline-block;
 margin-left: 2%;
}

footer{
 position: relative;
 background-color: red;
 font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
 <title>Alexandre | Desenvolvedor Web</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.css">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato|Open+Sans:300|Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Baloo+Bhaijaan|Montserrat|Slabo+27px" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<body>
 
 <header id="cabecalho">
  <h1>Alexandre | Front End Developer <i class="fa fa-code"></i></h1>
  <nav id="menu">
   <ul id="lista">
    <li> <a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sobre</a></li>
    <li> <a href="#">Contato</a></li>
    <li> <a href="#">Serviços</a></li>

   </ul>

  </nav>
   
 </header>

 <div id="banner"><p>Posso Te Ajudar A Ter Um Site Só Seu</p></div>

<section class="secao">

 <div class="servicos">
  <h2>Quem Sou Eu</h2>
  <p>Oi! Me chamo Alexandre e sou Desenvolvedor Front End.</p>
  <p>Isso quer dizer que se você tem uma empresa, um hobbie, ou um projeto e precisa de um site para exibir na web eu posso te ajudar.</p>
 </div>

 <div class="servicos">
  <h2>Serviços</h2>
  <p>Trabalho com desenvolvimento de sites usando as mais atuais tecnologias buscando os melhores resultados possíveis.</p>
 </div>



<div class="servicos tecnologias">

 <h2>Tecnologias Que Uso</h2>
 <div class="tecno">
  <figure>
   <img src="img/html5-badge-156.png" alt="logo html5">
   <figcaption>HTML5</figcaption>
   </figure>
 </div>

 <div class="tecno">
  <figure>
   <img src="img/css3-156.png" alt="logo css3">
   <figcaption>CSS3</figcaption>
  </figure>
 </div>

 <div class="tecno">
  <figure>
   <img src="img/javascript-156.png" alt="logo javascript">
   <figcaption>JAVASCRIPT</figcaption>
  </figure>
 </div>

 <div class="tecno">
  <figure>
   <img src="img/wordpress-156.png" alt="wordpress logo">
   <figcaption>WORDPRESS</figcaption>
  </figure>
 </div>

</div>
 </section>

<footer>
 <p>teste</p>

</footer>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: E como você quer que o footer fique?

Comment: Para o seu footer ficar sempre no final do ecrã vc tem que usar javascript, porque o tamanho do ecrã depende de cada utilizador. Vc está a dizer que o footer fica no meio do ecrã, no meu tenho que fazer scroll para o ver. Vc tem que pegar o tamanho do ecrã do cliente e depois ajustar seu footer de acordo com isso.

Comment: Eu quero que fique no fim da página. Achei que eu poderia estar errando em algum position no código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Percebi 3 problemas problemas no seu código:

1) Ausência da tag `<head></head>`.
2) `position: absolute;` na classe `.secao`: está fazendo com que o elemento com esta classe fique "solto" na página, ocasionando o `footer` no meio da página. Retire esse `position`.
3) Precisa dar forma, tamanho e posição para o `footer` (`display`, `width`, `float`):

```
   footer{
        position: relative;
        background-color: red;
        font-size: 40px;
        display: block;
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

```css
*{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 font-family:'Open Sans';
}

header{
 width: 100%;
 height: 65px;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 1;
}

h1{
 padding: 20px;
}

#menu ul{
 margin-right: 5%;
}

#menu li{
 margin-right: 0.5%;
 display: inline;
 padding: 20px;
 float: right;
}

#menu li a{
 color: #ffffff;
 font-family: 'Open Sans';
 text-decoration: none;
 padding: 10px;
}
#menu a:hover{
 text-decoration: underline;
}

h1{
 margin-left: 5%;
 color:#fff;
 text-decoration: none;
 float: left;
 font-size: 20px;
}

#banner{
 position: relative;
 background:url(img/code-3.jpeg) no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100vh;
 background-position:0px 0px ;
 /*margin-bottom: 30px;*/
}

#banner p{
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;
 color: #fff;
 font-family: 'Open Sans';
 font-size: 3.5em;
 top:48%;
 /*left: 400px;*/
}

.secao{
 width: 100%;
 /*height: 100vh;*/
 background-color: #eee;
}

.servicos{
 padding: 1.5%;
 margin-top: 60px;
 margin-left: 10%;
 width: 35%;
 float: left;
 border-radius:7px;
 /*height: 300px;*/
 color:#2d2d2d;
 /*background-color: #eee;*/
 text-align: center;
}

.servicos h2{
 font-family: 'Roboto';
 font-size: 2.4em;
 margin-bottom: 2%;
}

.servicos p{
 font-family: 'Open Sans';
 font-size: 120%;
 line-height: 30px;
 
}

.tecnologias{
 margin:10% 0;
 width: 100%; 
}

.tecnologias h2{
 margin-bottom: 4%;
}

.tecno{
 display: inline-block;
 margin-left: 2%;
}

footer{
 position: relative;
 background-color: red;
 font-size: 40px;
 display: block;
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header id="cabecalho">
 <h1>Alexandre | Front End Developer <i class="fa fa-code"></i></h1>
 <nav id="menu">
  <ul id="lista">
   <li> <a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Sobre</a></li>
   <li> <a href="#">Contato</a></li>
   <li> <a href="#">Serviços</a></li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
</header>
<div id="banner"><p>Posso Te Ajudar A Ter Um Site Só Seu</p></div>
<section class="secao">
 <div class="servicos">
  <h2>Quem Sou Eu</h2>
  <p>Oi! Me chamo Alexandre e sou Desenvolvedor Front End.</p>
  <p>Isso quer dizer que se você tem uma empresa, um hobbie, ou um projeto e precisa de um site para exibir na web eu posso te ajudar.</p>
 </div>
 <div class="servicos">
  <h2>Serviços</h2>
  <p>Trabalho com desenvolvimento de sites usando as mais atuais tecnologias buscando os melhores resultados possíveis.</p>
 </div>
 <div class="servicos tecnologias">
  <h2>Tecnologias Que Uso</h2>
  <div class="tecno">
   <figure>
    <img src="img/html5-badge-156.png" alt="logo html5">
    <figcaption>HTML5</figcaption>
   </figure>
  </div>
  <div class="tecno">
   <figure>
    <img src="img/css3-156.png" alt="logo css3">
    <figcaption>CSS3</figcaption>
   </figure>
  </div>
  <div class="tecno">
   <figure>
    <img src="img/javascript-156.png" alt="logo javascript">
    <figcaption>JAVASCRIPT</figcaption>
   </figure>
  </div>
  <div class="tecno">
   <figure>
    <img src="img/wordpress-156.png" alt="wordpress logo">
    <figcaption>WORDPRESS</figcaption>
   </figure>
  </div>
 </div>
</section>
<footer>
 <p>teste</p>
</footer>
```

Comment: Era exatamente isso, valeu mesmo,

Answer (score 0):

> "Acho que me expressei mal. Quero o footer no fim da página seguindo o
>   fluxo, como na maioria das páginas. Com o position fixed ele fica na
>   frente de outros elementos na página."

Você esta colocando em *.secao* como position: absolute; então o footer fica por atrás do *.secao*, por isso o footer desaparece e não segue o fluxo normal do site.